# Changes on checkbox state not recognize ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried to do a checkbox that changes the text when checkbox is checked or unchecked however it seems that the state was not changed even after the checkbox is triggered. I am trying to follow a tutorial and encounter this error which for some reason can't find what is the problem. Below is my current code.

```
var UseOfState = class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isCheck: true};
        this.toggleCheckbox = this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this);
    }

    toggleCheckbox () {
        console.log('checkbox triggered');
        this.setState = ({isCheck: !this.state.isCheck});
    }

    render () {
    console.log('render');
        var msg;
        if(this.state.isCheck) {
            msg = 'checked';
            console.log(this.state.isCheck);
        } else {
            msg = 'unchecked';
            console.log(this.state.isCheck);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggleCheckbox} defaultChecked={this.state.isCheck}/>
                <h3>Check box is {msg}</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<UseOfState/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OazZpa

I want to know where is my error from there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo on below line

```
this.setState = ({isCheck: !this.state.isCheck});
```

to

```
this.setState({isCheck: !this.state.isCheck});
```

Then it works fine.